# Batch script to move zip files based on year modified

Tags: date, batch-file, last-modified

I realize there are a lot of questions already answered about doing something similar. I have researched what I am trying to do and didn't find anything that seemed to apply to what I am trying to do. There are a few factors combined in what I am trying to do and *I don't know a lot about batch scripting*.

First, I need to look at zip files with a certain naming scheme only. The way these are named is file1234.zip, file2345.zip, file3456.zip, etc... This naming scheme is automatically generated and already in place. The number in the name has nothing to do with the date it was modified or created. There are other zip files in the source directory I would want to ignore. `This can be solved with wildcards. "file*.zip"`

Next, I need to move only certain files fitting the above criteria, that were modified within a specific year. i.e. move zip files modified in 2000 but leave all other files alone. The year the files were modified would be a constant and would be designated in the script.

When combined, if file2345.zip was modified in 2000 and the other files were last modified in other years, then file2345.zip would be moved and all others would be ignored.

What I have learned:

Wildcards are valid characters in the middle of a file name.

To get the dates modified for all files matching my naming criteria

```
forfiles /M file*.zip /C "cmd /c echo @file @fdate"
```

With the above, how do I look at just the four-digit year?

I have no objections to using xcopy or robocopy for the actual file move.

Any suggestions or ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Where's your script? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Do some research into that *lot of questions already answered about doing something similar*, and make an effort to adapt one of those answers to your situation. Then, once you've at least tried, you can describe what you've done, include the code you've got so far, and ask a *specific* question about that code. Good luck.

Comment: Here's a start `ls -lt files*.zip` or `find . -type f -newermt "3 years ago" ! -newermt "2 years ago"`

Comment: `forfiles /M file*.zip /C "cmd /c echo @file @fdate"`

This outputs the year as 8/21/2015. I want to compare the year here to a specific year, then continue based on that comparison. So, if the year = 2000 then do action, otherwise do nothing.

How can I have the batch file compare the year to a specific year?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this command `dir file*.zip |find /i "file"` shows something like this:

```
18/08/2015  11:58            45,617 file2456.zip
18/08/2015  11:58           156,789 file36789.zip
```

then this code should work:

```
@echo off
md "d:\new folder" 2>nul
for /f "tokens=3,*" %%a in ('dir file*.zip ^|find /i "file" ^|find "/2000 "') do move "%%b" "d:\new folder"
```